# How do I create a singular GET path for a resource including helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following:

`routes.rb`

```
resources :splashes, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
get '/splash', to: 'splashes#index'

>rake routes | grep splash
             splashes GET    /splashes(.:format)                                  splashes#index
                      POST   /splashes(.:format)                                  splashes#create
               splash DELETE /splashes/:id(.:format)                              splashes#destroy
                      GET    /splash(.:format)                                    splashes#index
```

However, when I try to use `splash_url`, it generates `http://localhost:3000/splashes/1`.

I tried

```
get '/splash', to: 'splashes#index', as: 'splash'
```

But it gave

> rake routes | grep splash
>   rake aborted!
>   ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'splash'
>   You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

I tried to use the singular `resource`, but it doesn't generate an `#index` action, and you can't DELETE a specific splash row.

Comment: Try changing `resources :splashes, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]` to `resources :splashes, only: [:create, :destroy]`

Comment: First, I don't get the point of using a *singular resource* for an `index` action which will have a **collection of resources**

Comment: @Pavan 1st comment: That didn't create a `*_url` helper for the GET path. 2nd comment: It is a _splash_ page, a _landing page_. Splashes doesn't make sense to humans or marketers, but that is how the table and controller is named. It's for lead generation. No records will be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place your singular routes **get** statement before the **resources** statement,

```
get '/splash', to: 'splashes#index'
resources :splashes, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
```

Now, the rake routs will give your the below result,

```
splash   GET    /splash(.:format)                                splashes#index
splashes GET    /splashes(.:format)                            splashes#index
         POST   /splashes(.:format)                            splashes#create
         DELETE /splashes/:id(.:format)                        splashes#destroy
```

By that above approach the **delete and get** routes get overrided based on the defintion sequence, because they both has the same named helpers **spash_path**. So, I suggest you to add named helper to custom **get /spash** routes like below,

```
resources :splashes, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
get '/splash', to: 'splashes#index', as: 'splash_index'
```

So, now you will get a separate named routes **splash_index** for your custom get route. There's a another solution also,

```
resources :splashes, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
resources :splash, only: [:index], controller: :splashes
```

So, that you will get a different named helper for your **/spash** routes,

```
splashes GET    /splashes(.:format)                           splashes#index
         POST   /splashes(.:format)                           splashes#create
splash DELETE /splashes/:id(.:format)                         splashes#destroy
splash_index GET    /splash(.:format)                         splashes#index
```

Comment: Wow that does work, but now the DELETE links don't work. `link_to 'Delete', splash_path(lead), method: :delete` yields `http://localhost:3000/splash.1`.

Comment: Yeah, I see the routes delete and get are overrided based on definition sequence, because they both has same named helpers spash_path. So, I suggest you to define a named route for "get /spash" and use that helper to get your expected o/p. I just have updated the answer also.

Comment: Thanks! I like the 2nd way but used the 1st way since it's closer to what I have.